# AS3 keyboard event not updating when going back to frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, keyboard-events, flash-cc

I am making an application about the atmosphere, and am trying to make a movie clip animate (move) up and down to different section when the arrow keys are pressed. It's almost working fine. However, if for instance I was on the section 'troposphere', pressing the up arrow key would take me up to 'stratosphere' and then the down arrow key back to 'troposphere'. The up arrow key would then take me back up to 'stratosphere', but if I press the up arrow key to then go up to 'mesosphere' it repeats the animation from 'troposphere' to 'stratosphere'.

I explained that the best I can, sorry if it's unclear. I uploaded a [screencap to youtube](http://youtu.be/Adm-CbHcXX4) that I think would help make it clear.

Here's my code for troposphere (the start) on frame 40. The animation to stratosphere starts on 41.

```
stop();

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, goupStrat);

function goupStrat(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.UP) {
        gotoAndPlay (41)
    }
}
```

And here's my code for stratosphere

```
stop();

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, goupMes);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, godownTropos);

function goupMes(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.UP) {
        gotoAndPlay (64);
    }
}

function godownTropos(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.DOWN) {
        gotoAndPlay (211);
    }
}
```

and so on.

[Here's what my timeline looks like](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1klubqj9g3upuld/layers.png?dl=0)

I have tried searching for a solution but I'm not sure exactly what it is I should be searching for.

Comment: gotoAndPlay (41)..Its probably this, try gotoandstop... its hard to say how you have your project set up... I advise not to use keyframe animations for the keyup  and down... you could use mymovieclip.tween.y position to up or down... if you understand what i mean

Comment: I basically have a 20ish frame animation to switch between each section when the key is pressed which is why I have 'gotoAndPlay'. I will give that a try though, thanks.

Comment: remember flash always plays forward on the timeline... so if you use gotoand stop then play the inner animation ...  its hard to say cause im not in front of your project...if you upload it some-where i will look at it

Comment: I have added a link to a screenshot of my timeline. The layer with animation moves the atmpsphere layers movieclip up or down when the key is pressed

Comment: Its hard as you have it on the timeline, its better to use scripting to do action-script not using key animations from key presses because  issue's and complications arise such as you have.... I think its better for you to rethink your approach to your project